# Adicionar elemento com base em comparação de arrays

Tags: javascript, json, array

Possuo dois arrays:

```
videos = [{
  "id": number,
  "title": string,
  "url": string
}]

watched = [{
  "video_id": number
}]
```

O "video_id" é adicionado quando um usuário assiste um video específico, este ID é o mesmo que está no array videos.

Preciso comparar os dois arrays, adicionar o elemento "watched" com base na seguinte comparação: `id === video_id`. Por exemplo:

```
videos = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "one",
    "url": "/v1",
    "watched": true
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "two",
    "url": "/v2"
    "watched": false
  }
];
```

Por enquanto eu comparei os objetos que contem as IDs condizentes da seguinte forma:

```
const watched_video = watched
      .filter((x) => x.watched)
      .map((x) => x.video_id);
```

Porém, não sei como adicionar o `watched: true` ao elemento que possui id's condizentes e `watched: false` aos que não possuem.

Edit:

Com base nas respostas, consegui resolver o problema com o seguinte código:

```
const watched_video = videos.map((v) => {
  if (watched.some((w) => w.video_id === v.id))
    return { ...v.dataValues, watched: true };
  return { ...v.dataValues, watched: false };
});
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender. Esse array `watched` tem um objeto com propiedade `watched` ou não? Pelo seu código somente `"video_id"`.

Comment: Voce quer adicionar o atributo `watched` no array `videos` com base nos `id`s que estão em `watched`?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Preciso adicionar o atributo watched e que ele seja true em todos os objetos que vídeo.id === watched.video_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que você tem um array com `id`s dos que já foram assistidos, a comparação pode ser feita usando somente o `map` e retornando o objeto formatado de acordo com uma condição (se o `id` deste objeto está na lista de assistidos `watched`).

Esta é somente uma soulção possível a qual você pode usar. Se eu entendi direito sua pergunta, você pode fazer o seguinte...

Veja o código:

```js
const videos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'one',
    url: '/v1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'two',
    url: '/v2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'two',
    url: '/v2',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'two',
    url: '/v2',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'two',
    url: '/v2',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: 'two',
    url: '/v2',
  },
];

const watched = [1, 3, 4];

const watched_video = videos.map((el) => {
  if (watched.includes(el.id)) return { ...el, watched: true };
  else return { ...el, watched: false };
});

console.log(watched_video);
```

- `if(watched.includes(el.id))` (apenas exemplo, ignore essa maneira como escrevi) é apenas uma meneira de verificar se o `id` está na lista de assistidos.
- Usamos `includes` para verificar se o `id` do objeto está na lista de assistidos.
- O `if/else` é usado para formatar e definir o valor de `watched`.

Comment: Entendi! 
Alterei um pouco a questão da verificação, mas funcionou certinho!
Só estou com um problema para retornar isso como um JSON, recebo o seguinte erro: Converting circular structure to JSON\n

Comment: Não entendi a mensagem de erro. Usou `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Veja o gist: https://gist.github.com/fredarend/fcdf011502eecb0f2675e19fce093b62

Incluí alguns comentários explicando.

Comment: Resolvido. Editei a questão.

Answer (score 2):

Fazendo uma mudança na nomenclatura do array `watched_video` para `watches` e supondo que os ids nos arrays `videos` e `watches` são únicos é possível criar uma instancia de [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) que permite, através do método [Set.prototype.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add), armazenar valores únicos de qualquer tipo. Nesse caso os ids dos videos assistidos.
As instancias `Set` também possuem o método [`Set.prototype.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) que retorna um valor booleano indicando se o elemento está ou não contido nesse conjunto.

Ciente dessas informações basta então iterar pelo array `watches` e salvar os ids dos filmes assistidos no `Set` nominado por `ids` e posteriormente iterar pelo array `videos` e para cada elemento adicionar a propriedade `watched`.

```js
let videos = [
  {"id": 1, "title": "one", "url": "/v1"},
  {"id": 2, "title": "two", "url": "/v2"},
  {"id": 3, "title": "three", "url": "/v3"},
  {"id": 4, "title": "four", "url": "/v4"},
]

let watches = [
  {"watched": true, "video_id": 1},
  {"watched": false, "video_id": 3},
  {"watched": true, "video_id": 4},
  {"watched": false,"video_id": 2}
]

let ids = new Set();                      //Inicializa o Set ids.

//Para cada elemento w de watches...
for (let w of watches) {
  if (w.watched) ids.add(w.video_id);     //...Se w.watched for true adiciona w.video_id em ids.
}

//Para cada elemento v de videos...
for (let v of videos) {
  v.watched = ids.has(v.id);             //...adiciona a propriedade watched ao elemento 
                                         //com o valor dependente de estar ou não contido em ids.
}

console.log(videos);
```